# How do I have the form inside the picture responsively move below the responsive image?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have two issues. 
- How can I have the form move below the picture below medium viewport? 
I am using Bootstrap for responsive image. I put a form inside the image. I want the image to jump outside of the image below medium viewport size and sit below it with its form changed to fit the viewport responsively. (It doesn't need to change the shape if it's hard)

- How can I prevent the image not to cover up the elements below?
  I tried to put margin on bottom of page and margin on top of the div below still doesn't get it done.

Thank you.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0 shrink-t0-fit-no">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="stylesSS SOF.css">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Raleway:wght@900&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
  <title>SOF</title>
</head>

<body>
  <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-dark bg-dark">
    <div class="navbar-brand">
      <img src="" class="navbar-brand" />
      <span id="slogan">SLOGAN</span>
    </div>
    <button class="navbar-toggler" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#mainNavBar">
      <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="mainNavBar">
      <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
        <li class="nav-item active">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">HOW IT WORKS <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">SIGN-IN</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item dropdown">
          <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
            OWNER
          </a>
          <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Sign up</a>
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Supply</a>
          </div>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </nav>

  <div id="showcase">
    <img src="images/Concert.jpg" id="showcase-pic" alt="bedroom-day">
  </div>
  
  <div class="card" id="reserve-form" style="width:350px" pl-5 pr-5>
    <div class="card-title">
      <h4>Select</h4>
    </div>
    <div class="card-body">
      <form>
       <div class="form-group">
          <label for="Area">Area</label>
          <input type="text" class="form-control" id="Area" aria-describedby="area" placeholder="Near me?">
          <small class="form-text text-muted">Search</small>
          
          <label for="numberOfGuests"></label>
          <select class="custom-select" id="number">
            <option selected>Party</option>
            <option value="1">1</option>
            <option value="2">2</option>
            <option value="3">3</option>
            <option value="4">4</option>
          </select>
          <small class="form-text text-muted">max</small>
       </div>

       <div class="form-group">
          <label for="arrivalTime">From when</label>
          <select class="custom-select" id="arrivalTime">
            <option selected>Pick time</option>
            <option value="11">11am</option>
            <option value="12">12pm</option>
            <option value="1">1pm</option>
            <option value="2">2pm</option>
            <option value="3">3pm</option>
            <option value="4">4pm</option>
          </select>
          
          <label for="departureTime">To when</label>
          <select class="custom-select" id="departureTime">
            <option selected>Pick</option>
            <option value="2">12pm</option>
            <option value="3">1pm</option>
            <option value="1">2pm</option>
            <option value="2">3pm</option>
            <option value="3">4pm</option>
            <option value="1">5pm</option>
            <option value="1">6pm</option>
            <option value="1">7pm</option>
          </select>
        </div>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Vel nostrum, temporibus illum similique corrupti dolor quo id cupiditate iusto soluta nisi quos officiis recusandae, est doloribus. Maxime quam dolorem minima excepturi pariatur quaerat, alias labore suscipit. Sit corporis a eum? </p></div>

  
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Magnam omnis ab qui. Aliquam asperiores sit soluta aspernatur ratione illum? Ducimus voluptatibus, ipsam minus obcaecati pariatur omnis dicta ex quas dignissimos?</p>
 
 
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-J6qa4849blE2+poT4WnyKhv5vZF5SrPo0iEjwBvKU7imGFAV0wwj1yYfoRSJoZ+n" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-Q6E9RHvbIyZFJoft+2mJbHaEWldlvI9IOYy5n3zV9zzTtmI3UksdQRVvoxMfooAo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-wfSDF2E50Y2D1uUdj0O3uMBJnjuUD4Ih7YwaYd1iqfktj0Uod8GCExl3Og8ifwB6" crossorigin="anonymous"></script> 
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can you upload an example with image?

Comment: Simone, googled a bit but not sure how to upload images in comment. They say put in the links but the site is not up and running yet. Do you know another way to upload images?

Comment: Go [here](https://it.imgbb.com/) upload image, then edit your post and post link or here.